# Show Data Grid View specified cell value in Textbox

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, textbox

I am a student programmer who is learning VB. I am trying to make a telephone book type project in VB (Windows Forms). In my project I am using an unbound Data Grid View control. Below the Data Grid View, I have some textboxes which will display the values of the selected row. On the form load event, my program accesses a file and populates the Data Grid View control with values from the file. This works perfectly, but the problem I get is when I use the code:

```
 txtLast.Text = dgvMain.Rows.Item(0).Cells(0).Value
```

to populate the textbox called txtLast with the value at the specified cell, the textbox doesn't display the value. The program doesn't crash or hang, it simply won't display the value and when I try to edit the textbox, it acts as if the textbox is empty. I have tried using

```
 txtLast.Text = dgvMain.Rows.Item(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
```

as well as trying to refresh my Data Grid View control and the textbox. Nothing has worked so far. When I use a breakpoint to see whether that line of code is executed, the autos window shows me that the line of code is executed and that it sees the value of the specified cell as "Smith". However, when I press F11 to step into the next line, the textbox.text property remains as "" instead of changing to "Smith".

Note: when I manually specify the text through the code (i.e. txtLast.Text = "Test") it will show that text. Also, this problem is not with just one textbox, it is with every textbox that I use (I have 5 textboxes showing various values from the specified row). The weird thing is that out of the 5 textboxes, one of them, the masked textbox which shows the phone number works perfectly with the same line of code. (note it is not a problem only affecting regular textboxes as I have tried using both regular textboxes and masked textboxes, both produce the same problem except for the phone textbox).

Also, I would prefer to keep the Data grid view unbound (not connected to a database) and the textboxes unbound (not connected to the data grid view as a data source) because while browsing the internet I have seen people suggesting to bind the textbox or data grid view, however I do not understand how to do so, and I believe that this can be done without binding to a data source.

Any help is appreciated in trying to figure out why the text doesn't change. Let me know if you need any other info or if part of my explanation is unclear.

Thanks!

Comment: If that code is in the Load event handler then it may well be throwing an exception but it would just be swallowed.  Try wrapping it in a Try...Catch block to see what the exception is.  That said, why not just use data-binding?  You can populate a list of some sort and then bind it to both the grid and the `TextBox`.  No code at all required.

Comment: How would I bind the grid to the textbox (I'd rather leave the data gridview as it is)? For example, I would like to bind the value in the last name column to the textbox txtLast so that when a user selects a row it shows the last name of that contact. Btw, in my grid, the last name column is at index 1.

Comment: You wouldn't bind the grid to the `TextBox`.  You would bind the grid and the `TextBox` to the same data.  If you don't want to bind the grid then that's not an option.

Comment: Oh ok, then binding is out of the question. I tried using the Try Catch block, however it did not throw any exceptions. Is there anything else I can do to get this working? I don't see any other way of doing something similar and I can't just leave this out of the program because it is an important part of the Telephone book program that I am making. Thanks for your suggestions and help!

Comment: Either that code throws an exception or it executes successfully.  If it executes successfully then the `TextBox` will contain the value from that cell afterwards.  If you're not seeing anything in the `TextBox` then either you're clearing it after that line or the cell contains an empty `String` or something that converts to an empty `String`, e.g. `Nothing` or `DBNull.Value`.  You need to debug to determine which.  If you put a breakpoint on that line, what is the value in the cell and, if you step, what is the contents of the `TextBox`?